# Is there a permanent review ban?

Tags: support, review-audits, review-suspension

If I fail a sufficent number of audits, would I get permanently banned from [review queues](https://stackoverflow.com/review)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, at least [not automatically](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/174118/the-time-of-automatic-review-bans-should-be-increased-with-every-new-ban/190562#comment591020_190562) – the first ban is 2 days, then (if you fail another audit within 30 days) 7 days, then (if you fail *another* audit within 30 days) 30 days. After that, the cycle starts again. But I guess that in severe cases, or cases of repeated offense, the moderators can hand out longer or permanent review bans.